# DataGridView.Invoke throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i have a problem with DataGridView.Invoke.

```
delegate void CheckMainTableCallback();
static void CheckMainTable()
{
    if (Program.MonitorApp.ServersTable.InvokeRequired)
    {
        CheckMainTableCallback Safe = new CheckMainTableCallback(CheckMainTable);
        MonitorApp.ServersTable.Invoke(Safe);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in MonitorApp.MainTable.Rows)
        {
            **r.Cells["Load"].Value = 
                (Servers.Find(
                    p => p.NAME == r.Cells[0].ToString()
                )
                .GetSystemValue("% Proccess Usage"));** // exception here
        }
    }
}
```

so i call CheckMainTable to get values from ServersTable ( using by another thread ) to my MainTable.
and it throws NullReference.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which part of your code throws the exception?

Comment: @DeeMac r.Cells["Load"].Value = (Servers.Find(p => p.NAME == r.Cells[0].ToString()).GetSystemValue("% Proccess Usage"));

Comment: Which part of that code? Be as specific as possible. When debugging, what property reference gives you this exception?

Comment: @DeeMac here: p.NAME == r.Cells[0].ToString(). I think it is a thread conflict coz reading p.NAME field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So tracking down an exception like this is a piece-by-piece process. Consider the fact that this line of code:

```
r.Cells[0].ToString()
```

could throw if `r.Cells[0]` is `null`.

Further, `.GetSystemValue` would throw if the result from `Servers.Find(...` were `null`.

Comment: thanks, u gave me right direction to solve my problem, here is the answer: p.NAME == r.Cells[0].Value.ToString()

Comment: @Greag.Deay, yep, you could use `Convert.ToString(r.Cells[0].Value) too. That way if the cells value is `null` it won't throw.